# Turning one-line-per-event into one-line-per-patient, but keeping dates of EACH time different types of event occurred

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Edit: When I made my toy model, I hadn't realized people would (very logically) latch on to the redundancy of the variables diagnosis and *_disorder. In the real dataset, the diagnosis variable is an ICD code (with letters and numbers - categoric), and *many* different ICD codes are lumped into each *_disorder variable. In addition, a single claim may fall under more than one type of disorder. This was what led to the creation of the dummy variables for each type of disorder. I had thought it might be more clear if I just wrote out the diagnosis with words to emphasize how they were rolled into the *_disorder variables. Definitely an oversimplification, and a beginner mistake! I have edited the values of the diagnosis variable to reflect this.

Also, the purpose of this is not just a report. These data are from pregnant women. This is all going to be linked with birth records and social services data, and *each* diagnosis event (what I am hoping to have as mood_1, mood_2, anxiety_1, etc.) will be flagged for when it occurs in relation to the woman's pregnancy/ies. However, the linkage to these other datasets will happen via the ID variable, which is why I really need to get this to a single line per person. From there, the data will be the basis for fairly extensive analysis, including linear regression and basic descriptive statistics.

Thank you so, so, SO much to those who have given their time and effort to answer. I was really worried I would post here and get no responses, but it seems like that worry was unfounded! :)

Original question: I have a dataset consisting of individual Medicaid claims with patients’ ID numbers, where each claim is flagged for whether or not it contains certain mental illness diagnoses. I’m trying to turn that into a dataset with one line per patient showing the date(s) of each diagnosis of interest. I’m going to use a toy model because this is a pretty conceptual question, and I am actually using protected health information on a secure server. The real data is similar to this, but there are 25 flagged mental illness diagnoses and 96 million claims for 250,000 people. Here’s what I have to start with (one line per claim):

```
ID  diagnosis   claim_date  mood_disorder anxiety_disorder 
1   F60.72      23JAN2019   1           0 
1   F60.3       16DEC2018   1           0 
1   F65.51      04MAY2019   0           1 
1   B20.2       28FEB2008   0           0 
2   F65.3       05JUL2018   0           1 
2   B20.5       28OCT2017   0           0 
3   B20.6       20OCT2016   0           0
```

Here’s what I want (one line per person):

```
ID  mood_1          mood_2          anxiety_1 
1   23JAN2019       16DEC2018       0 
2   0               0               05JUL2018 
3   0               0               0
```

I cannot drop patient 3 from the dataset, as I need to know whether they were present in the Medicaid data, regardless of whether they had a mental illness diagnosis.

In a previous iteration of this problem, I only needed to know whether or not the person had had each of the diagnoses (at all), making the dates irrelevant. This was the code I had used:

```
%macro collapse_to_id; 
    %do i = 1 %to 2; 
        %if &i = 1 %then %let var = mood_disorder; 
        %if &i = 2 %then %let var = anxiety_disorder; 

        proc sort data = lib.original_dataset; by id descending &var.; run; 
        data sorted_dataset_&i.; 
            set lib.original_dataset; 
            by id descending &var.; 
            if first.id; 
        run; 
    %end; 
%mend; 

%collapse_to_id; 

data lib.final_dataset; 
    merge stored_dataset_1-stored_dataset_2; 
    by id; 
run;
```

This would give me an intermediate output like this:

(dataset stored_dataset_1)

```
ID  diagnosis   claim_date  mood_disorder       anxiety_disorder 
1   F60.72      23JAN2019   1           0 
2   F65.3       05JUL2018   0           0 
3   B20.6       20OCT2016   0           0
```

(dataset stored_dataset_2)

```
ID  diagnosis   claim_date  mood_disorder       anxiety_disorder 
1   F65.51      04MAY2019   0           1 
2   F65.3       05JUL2018   0           1 
3   B20.6       20OCT2016   0           0
```

Which would merge to give a final output like this: (I think? I don’t remember what happens to variables diagnosis and claim_date, but I think they get overwritten, and it didn’t matter here.)

```
ID  diagnosis   claim_date  mood_disorder       anxiety_disorder 
1   F65.51      04MAY2019   1           1 
2   F65.3       05JUL2018   0           1 
3   B20.6       20OCT2016   0           0
```

Looking back, I’m not actually sure how the mood_disorder and anxiety_disorder variables would come out here, either – I am thinking I should have dropped the diagnoses that were not “of interest” from each intermediate dataset to avoid having them get overwritten when those datasets are merged. For example, I think sorted_dataset_1 should have contained only variables (id, diagnosis, claim date, mood_disorder). I am (now) worried that the way I actually did it, the value of mood_disorder from sorted_dataset_2 overwrote that from sorted_dataset_1, such that patient 1 would have mood_disorder = 0 and anxiety_disorder = 1...

Anyway, more to the point (and regardless of whether the first attempt was correct), this approach obviously won’t work here, because I need to keep the dates of ALL claims for each type of disorder for my final dataset. Please help, and please be kind – first-time poster and new SAS user. I did find one post here with a similar-ish query, but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to my situation. :( Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your *_DISORDER variables are redundant to the DISEASE variable. Is this true in your actual data? If not which of the two should be used?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the new dataset that you can't do with the current one? Is this just for a report (print out)?

Comment: I edited my post, but DIAGNOSIS and *_DISORDER are not redundant. I need to use the *_DISORDER variables. This dataset will be merged with birth records and social services data using the mom's ID (hence needing one line per person), and will then undergo linear regression modeling & descriptive analysis. Thank you for helping clarify this!

Comment: Is it possible for one record to be classified as multiple disorders?

Comment: Yes, one claim (one record/entry) can fall under more than one disorder. I have edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Diagnosis maps to `kind_disorder=1` and transposed columns are based on `kind`.

First, throw away the macro coding mindset.  None needed here!

Pivoting your wonderfully tall categorical data into a wide array'ified form will require computing the desired column name in the transposed form.

Instead of transforming the data perhaps consider simply reporting it in a wide way.

Example:

The diagnosis kind type sequence number is tracked within id and used in calculating the desired column name. The hash reference counts the number of times a diagnosis is encountered as reading through the group.

One issue with calculating kind names in the order that the diagnoses occur is that the across order of the names may not appear 'all together'.  The names in use need to be accumulated and sorted *linguistically* to force transposed names to be grouped across-wise.

Mock data generation is used to simulate to a slightly larger sample data set.

```
* mock diagnosis codes 001 to 100 map to a kind of diagnosis;

data codes(keep=code kind);
  call streaminit(20230227);
  kinds = 'mood anxiety heart liver lung nankle nelbow pcough qvision rheadache sringing tswelling vbruising';
  kinds_count = countw(kinds);
  do x = 1 to 100;
    length code $3 kind $100;
    code = put(x,z3.);

    * makes the first 5 kinds occur 75% of the time;
    r = rand('uniform');
    if r < 0.75
      then kind_index = rand('integer', 1, 5);
      else kind_index = rand('integer', 6, kinds_count);

    kind = scan(kinds,kind_index);
    output;
  end;
run;

* custom format to perform the code to kind mapping;

data code_format;
  set codes;
  fmtname = '$code_to_kind';
  rename code=start;
  rename kind=label;
run;
proc format cntlin = code_format;
run;

* mock claims that use the mock diagnoses;

data claims(keep=id claim_date diagnosis kind flag) ;
  call streaminit(20230227);
  do id = 1 to 100;
    claim_date = rand('integer',1,100) + today() - 3650;
    do claims_count = 1 to rand('integer',1,10);
      diagnosis = put(rand('integer',1,100),z3.);
      kind = diagnosis; /* used in tranpose, VAR ID and FORMAT */
      claim_date + rand('integer', 35);
      flag = 1;
      output;
    end;
  end;
  format claim_date date9.;
run;

* transpose the mock data into the form same as question ;

proc transpose data=claims suffix=_disorder out=have(drop=_name_);
  by id claim_date;
  copy diagnosis;
  var flag;
  id kind;
  format kind $code_to_kind. ;
run;
```

Determine the kind of disorder by looking for the <kind>_disorder variable that is equal to 1.

```
data have_2 (keep=id diagnosis claim_date across_column_name) / view=have_2;
  set have end=end; 
  by id;

  length across_column_name $32;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    retain _1_ 1;
    declare hash types(suminc:'_1_');
    types.defineKey('diagnosis');
    types.defineDone();

    /* for forcing column names to be ordered */
    declare hash names();
    names.defineKey('across_column_name');
    names.defineData('_1_', 'across_column_name');
    names.defineDone();
  end;

  if first.id then types.clear();
  types.ref();

  across_column_name = cats(diagnosis,sum(types.sum(sum:_sum_),_sum_));
  names.replace();

  if end then do;
    names.output(dataset:'names(rename=_1_=id)');
  end;
run;

proc transpose data=have_2 out=want_prep(drop=_name_);

* filtering reduces wideness;
* where diagnosis in ('mood', 'anxiety');

  by id;
  var claim_date;
  id across_column_name;
run;

proc sort sortseq=linguistic(numeric_collation=on) data=names ;
  by across_column_name;
run;

proc transpose data=names out=names_ordered_across(drop=_name_);
  by id;
  id across_column_name;
run;

data want;
  merge have(keep=id) names_ordered_across want_prep;
  by id;
  if first.id;
run;
```

Intermediate data with calculated column name
[image]

Transposed data
[image]

*** OR Create a REPORT showing the data in an across manner ***;

```
data havekind;
  set have;
  array nums _numeric_;
  length kind $32;
  do _i_ = 1 to dim (nums) while (missing(kind));
    if nums(_i_) = 1 then do;
      varname = lowcase(vname(nums(_i_)));
      if scan(varname,-1,'_') = 'disorder' then
        kind = substr(varname,1,index(varname,'_disorder')-1);
    end;
  end;
  keep id claim_date kind;
run;

proc sort data=havekind out=havesorted;
  by id kind;

  * filtering reduces wideness;
  where kind in ('mood', 'anxiety');
run;

* id without filtered diagnoses requires one row with a diagnosis and missing claim date
* in order to appear in the report;

proc sql;
  create table emptyids as 
  select distinct id, (select min(kind) from havesorted) as kind, . as claim_date
  from have
  where id not in (select id from havesorted)
;

data havesorted;
  set emptyids havesorted;
  by id kind;
  if first.kind then num=1; else num+1;
  across_column_name = cats(kind,num);
run;

ods html file='report.html' style=plateau;
proc report data=havesorted;

  define id / group;
  define across_column_name / ' ' across;
  define claim_date / ' ';
  column id claim_date,across_column_name;
run;
ods html close;
```

`Proc REPORT` output is a file such as html or pdf. Filtering on diagnosis kind means fewer columns.

[image]

Comment: Hi Richard,
Thanks so much for your answer! I am pretty new to SAS, and I wasn't familiar with the hash reference. Although I made a mistake in how I described my diagnosis variable (making it look redundant with the *_disorder variables), it seems like the hash idea will still be useful?
Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is the road plan I'm considering:
1) Use the hash to count how many times a "1" appears under mood_disorder. 2) Use that to create a variable like your "across_column" for mood. 3) Repeat for other disorders. I am shooting for exactly your "transposed data" table. TYSM!

Comment: It will be a little more complicated.  You will need to array all the numeric variables and loop over them looking for the `1`, at which point the `VNAME()` can tell you the name of the variable of the array element -- strip off `_disorder` and you are where I was with `diagnosis`.  I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

If the input data is large you probably want to use a data step to do the collapsing.  Essentially you just need to use array(s) and BY group processing.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  array flags anxiety_disorder mood_disorder heart_disorder ;
  array counts anxiety_count mood_count heart_count;
  array dates [3,2] anxiety1-anxiety2 mood1-mood2 heart1-heart2;
  retain anxiety1-anxiety2 mood1-mood2 heart1-heart2 ;
  format anxiety1-anxiety2 mood1-mood2 heart1-heart2 date9.;
  if first.id then call missing(of counts[*] dates[*]);
  do index=1 to dim(flags);
    if flags[index] then do;
       counts[index]+1;
       dates[index,counts[index]]=claim_date;
    end;
  end;
  if last.id;
  drop diagnosis claim_date index;
run;
```

You will need to know how many new variables you want before running the data step.  And you might need to do some checking that the counts do not extend beyond the size of the arrays.

Results:

[image]

It is not clear what value the DATES actual give you for doing analyses that just the counts do not. Any analysis that needs to compare the dates is probably done more easily with the vertical structure.